# Deserialize вариационных (типизированных) XML

Tags: c#, xml, serializable, unserialize

Раньше не сталкивался с сериализацией объектов, особенно с сериализацией в **`XML`** и обратно, но пришлось - да не знаю как быть с объектами в которых присутствует поле класса **`Object`**, в котором могут быть объекты нескольких типов.

Пример `XML`:

```
<Entities xmlns="http://site.ru/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Error i:nil="true"/>
  <Package xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:anyType i:type="TypeA">
      <ID>123</ID>
      <Number>1001</Number>
    </a:anyType>
    <a:anyType i:type="TypeB">
      <ID>232</ID>
      <Type>1001</Type>
    </a:anyType>
    <a:anyType i:type="TypeC">
      <ID>943</ID>
      <Name>TheName</Name>
    </a:anyType>
  </Package>
</Entities>
```

Пример `XML`:

```
<Entities xmlns="http://site.ru/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Error>
    <Message>Error Message</Message>
  <Error/>
  <Package i:nil="true"/>
</Entities>
```

Предполагаю, что классы можно записать так (хотя в записи не уверен, ибо не работает):

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Entities", Namespace = "http://site.org/", IsNullable = false)]
public class BoxPackages {
  [XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
  public BoxError Error;
  [XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
  public object[] Package;
}

public class BoxError {
    public String Message;
}

[XmlRootAttribute("TypeA")]
public class PackageTypeA {
  public Int32 ID;
  public Int64 Number;
}

[XmlRootAttribute("TypeB")]
public class PackageTypeB {
  public Int32 ID;
  public Byte Type;
}

[XmlRootAttribute("TypeC")]
public class PackageTypeC {
  public Int32 ID;
  public String Name;
}
```

Понятно, что классов не достаточно - нужна ещё какая-то настройка сериализатора.
Кто знает, как настроить сериализатор (**`XmlAttributes`** из коробки) для десериализации *`XML`* в объект типа **`BoxPackages`**? Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Продолжающий тему вопрос: [WCF DataContractSerializer неожиданные эллементы xmlns=""][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/133676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `XmlSerializer` умеет сериализовать только известные типы. Т.к. в массве `object[]` может быть любой объект любого типа, в конструкторе этого класса надо перечислить все возможные типы объектов, которые предполагается использовать:

```
 Type [] extraTypes = new Type[3];
 extraTypes[0] = typeof(PackageTypeA);
 extraTypes[1] = typeof(PackageTypeB);
 extraTypes[2] = typeof(PackageTypeC);

 // Create the XmlSerializer instance.
 XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BoxPackages),extraTypes);
```

Этот пример основан на [XmlSerializer - конструктор](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e5aakyae.aspx).

Comment: Этот пример генерирует XML вида

      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
      <Teacher xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Name>Mike</Name> 
        <Info>
          <anyType xsi:type="Address">
            <City>Springville</City> 
          </anyType>
          <anyType xsi:type="Phone">
            <PhoneNumber>555-0100</PhoneNumber> 
          </anyType>
        </Info>
        <PhoneInfo xsi:type="InternationalPhone">
        <CountryCode>000</CountryCode> 
        </PhoneInfo>
      </Teacher>

Comment: Код по ссылке действительно генерирует очень похожий код:

      <Teacher xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Name>Mike</Name> 
        <Info>
          <anyType xsi:type="Address">
            <City>Springville</City> 
          </anyType>
          <anyType xsi:type="Phone">
            <PhoneNumber>555-0100</PhoneNumber> 
          </anyType>
        </Info>
        <PhoneInfo xsi:type="InternationalPhone">
        <CountryCode>000</CountryCode> 
        </PhoneInfo>
      </Teacher>

Comment: По сути между <anyType xsi:type="Address"> и <a:anyType i:type="TypeA"> разница только в названии алиаса для пространства имен: xsi или i. С точки зрения парсеров это не приципиально. Ну а название типа выберите какое угодно.

Comment: > между <anyType xsi:type="Address"> и <a:anyType i:type="TypeA"> разница только в названии алиаса

Простите, видимо ошибся при наборе. Я имел введу, что у меня не

    <anyType xsi:type="TypeA">

а такой вид

    <a:anyType i:type="TypeA">

Comment: Как я понял, вы делаете только десериализацию, а за сериализацию в xml отвечает сторонний код? Попробуйте сами написать и сериализатор и сравнить свой xml со сторонним. 
У меня есть посленяя зацепка: здесь явно указано пространство имен 
<code> <Package xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"></code>
Поэтому стоит попробовать в атрибуте XmlArray его тоже явно указать:
<code>
 [XmlArray(IsNullable = true, Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
  public object[] Package;
</code>